# How to optimize CSS background-image and background-position properties

Tags: css, optimization, pycharm

I'm following a tutorial on front-end development, and I just wrote this ruleset for a header image:

```css
header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#00000070, #00000070), url("../img/hero.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

PyCharm tells me the `background-image` and `background-position` properties can be optimized by transforming them to a shorthand form, but it doesn't provide specific advice on how. As I'm a beginner to CSS, I can't infer the problem, and w3schools.com didn't offer any shorthand. How else can I write this block to shorten it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined by the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) there should be a slash separating the backgound-size from the background-position and an comma to separate the image from your gradient:

```
background:
    url("../img/hero.jpg")              /* image */
    center / cover,                     /* position / size */
    linear-gradient(red, green)         /* gradient */
;
```

In one line without comments:

```
background: url("../img/hero.jpg") center / cover, linear-gradient(red, green);
```

Comment: That did it, except you're missing a comma after the `url` property. Here's the working one-liner that gets rid of PyCharm's warning: `url("../img/hero.jpg"), center / cover, linear-gradient(red, green);` Edit your reply and I'll mark it the Correct Answer.

Comment: @Stobber That comma isn't needed, as you can see here in Example 15 for the paragraph element: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Comment: Hm. PyCharm 2017.1.4 doesn't allow the statement without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header { 
 background: linear-gradient(#00000070, #00000070), url("../img/hero.jpg"), center, cover}
```

Comment: Although I am unsure of linear-gradient.

Comment: The background property doesn't use the comma to separate attributes like position, try removing those: `background: linear-gradient(#00000070, #00000070) url("../img/hero.jpg") center cover`